# Change or reset default download application in Firefox

Tags: firefox, mime-type, file-association

Every time I download a file in Firefox with an unknown extension, Firefox offers to open it with `Password Gorilla (default)`.

Firefox does show the proper application for known file types, e.g. pdf.

When the download is finished and I click on the file in the download list that Firefox maintains, it tries to open the file with `Password Gorilla`.

If I however open a file browser and then click on the file, it is opened using the proper application.

`Password Gorilla` is an application that I use to keep my passwords safe. I don't have a clue why it has become the default for all unknown file types. It should only be associated with .psafe3 file extensions.

How can I change or reset the default for unknown file types?

I'm using Firefox 40.0.3 under Ubuntu 14.04 and GNOME Shell 3.10.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox used the application defined in

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

for type application/octet-stream under [Default Applications].

In my case it was like this :

```
[Default Applications]
application/octet-stream=geany.desktop
```

You can set it to another application. If you remove this line, firefox will used the one defined under [Added Associations].

If you remove also the application/octet-stream under [Added Associations], then firefox will give you only the option to save the file.

Comment: In my case, I removed all the lines, so now firefox only downloads the file. When I click on it in the download pop-up, it's gnome who handles the filetype and it usually open the right application.

Comment: Since ubuntu 15.04 (and maybe 14.10), this file is now in ~/.config/mimeapps.list